# PL Sql Parsing # Character

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a records in table which contains only one column,and its column contains data like under string.

> D#1001111068#112B#0010040130022013012111505444##20130121110800#20130121115054#01#-##240#username#username#20130124171831#20130130#6

Between # chracters every string show one column in other table like that.

```
D# 
1001111068#                          --Customer Number 
112B#                                --Procut Id 
0010040130022013012111505444#        --Serial Number 
#                                    --Order Number(empty record)     
20130121110800#                      --X Columns
```

I want to parse these items and insert to other table.
How to write this.

Comment: it is easier to parse it on the application level.

Comment: i know it,but our design isnt allowed it,i must solve in procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract n-th substring by the following expression:

```
regexp_substr(source_string, '([^#]*)(#|$)', 1, n, '', 1)
```

Full query:

```
create table your_table(
   source_string varchar2(4000)
);

insert into your_table
values('D#1001111068#112B#0010040130022013012111505444##20130121110800#20130121115054#01#-##240#username#username#20130124171831#20130130#6');

select 
  n,
  regexp_substr(source_string, '([^#]*)(#|$)', 1, n, '', 1) 
from your_table,
(
  select level as n from dual 
  connect by level <= (
    select max(regexp_count(source_string, '#')) + 1 
    from your_table
  )
) 
where n <= regexp_count(source_string, '#') + 1;
```

Output:

```
1   D
2   1001111068
3   112B
4   0010040130022013012111505444
5   (null)
6   20130121110800
7   20130121115054
8   01
9   -
10  (null)
11  240
12  username
13  username
14  20130124171831
15  20130130
16  6
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/048f9/2)

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm).